Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 3 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details also no apps connected
Gradle daemon error
My app does not start and when I restart on metro it gives no apps connected also
"Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 3 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details"
Here is the whole terminal
i - run on iOS
a - run on Android
d - open Dev Menu
r - reload app
info Opening app on Android...
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 3 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
info Reloading connected app(s)...
warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.

History restored

Also no gradle command is working it spends time and initialization is 0
I think there something wrong with gradle daemon and android studio.
